# How to make mathematical sense of the following statement?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

> A randomly chosen number N satisfying $N ≡ 3(6)$ has zero probability of being prime.

I was thinking about the Prime Number Theorem but I'm not sure about how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that "probability" here should be interpreted in the sense of asymptotic density. In that case the prime number theorem is not needed. Instead, note that $N=6k+3$ for some integer $k$. How often is such an $N$ prime?

Comment: Well, twice actually.

Comment: And every finite set has density zero...

Comment: Correct.........